# How associated Pending Intent with method

Tags: android, android-intent, android-pendingintent

I try to work with pending intent, I read documentation, examples on the net and questions/answers here. But still I'm confused about possibilities of pending intent.  All examples I found work with NotificationManager, AlarmManager, Home Screen AppWidgetManager.

**Is there method/operation how to associated own code(function, method) with pending intent ?** (So from app A i can send intent with Pending Intent in extras and then from B perfom operation on Pending intent with permissions and rights of A)

**How associated operation(function/method) with Pending Intent ?**

App A(sets Pending intent and start B)

```
    Intent i = getPackageManager().getLaunchIntentForPackage("lubo.app_private_key_demo2");
    i.setAction("testAction");
    PendingIntent pi = PendingIntent.getActivity(this.getApplicationContext(), 0, i, PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT);

    try {
        pi.send();
    }
    catch(PendingIntent.CanceledException ex){
        //ERROR
    }
```

App B(gets Pending intent from extras and try to call send()), from onCreate(..) method:

```
    Intent intent = getIntent();
    String action = intent.getAction();
    if(action.equals("testAction")){
        PendingIntent pi = null;
        pi = (PendingIntent) intent.getParcelableExtra("pendingIntent");
        Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "Got intent from demo1", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        if(pi != null){
            try {
                pi.send();
            } catch (PendingIntent.CanceledException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
            Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "I have pending intent ", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        }
        Log.d(TAG, "Got intent from demo1");
    }
```

Thanks.

**Edited code:** 
App A:

```
    Intent i = getPackageManager().getLaunchIntentForPackage("lubo.app_private_key_demo2");
    i.setAction("testAction");
    PendingIntent pi = PendingIntent.getActivity(this.getApplicationContext(), 0, i, PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT);

    try {
        pi.send();
    }
    catch(PendingIntent.CanceledException ex){
        //ERROR
    }
```

App B:

```
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    Intent intent = getIntent();
    String action = intent.getAction();
    if(action.equals("testAction")){
        PendingIntent pi = null;
        Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "Got intent from demo1", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        Log.d(TAG, "Got intent from demo1" + alias);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

So what happens when you say it's not working?

In your particular example you're calling the same activity that's already running. Which since you're using flag update current it will just refresh the extras.

Here's a good example of how to use PendingIntents http://iserveandroid.blogspot.com/2011/03/how-to-launch-pending-intent.html

Comment: thanks for reaction, I edited the code according to tutorial, and not working I meant, when I try to access app private keys of app A, from app B(started through Pending Intents), it's unsuccessful. So I think i must associated operation key access to pending intent. But I don't know how. Am i right ?